# Reshaping Image for PyTorch

Tags: python, image, opencv, keras, pytorch

I used to use keras and the image format it followed is [Height x Width x Channels x Samples]. i decided to switch to PyTorch. But i didn’t switch out my data loading schemes. So now i have numpy arrays of shape HxWxCxS, instead of SxCxHxW which is required for PyTorch. Does anyone have any idea to convert this ?

Comment: Please post some minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, Keras format is `(samples, height, width, channels)`.
All you need to do is a `moved = numpy.moveaxis(data, -1,1)`

If by luck you were using the non-default config `"channels_first"`, then the config is identical to that of PyTorch, which is `(samples, channels, height, width)`.

And when transforming to torch: `data = torch.from_numpy(moved)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your numpy arrays to tensors in pytorch quite easily by using the from_numpy function:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(5)
b = torch.from_numpy(a)
```

b is now useable in pytorch